# Can't access local file with webview android

Tags: android, excel, url, webview, google-docs

I want display excel file from my local PC,

but it show this alert

[image]

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String filename ="http://192.168.18.208:8080/files/6d9fdd50-89a6-11e8-b26a-cd4412cc6d5e-lengkap.xlsx";
    webview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // do your stuff here
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: put your local server online in this way it will not work

Comment: @Lely Suju try this `webview.loadUrl(filename);` instead of  `webview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);`

Comment: i'm sorry this is didn't work @userI

Comment: @Lely Suju have you tried this url link on your desktop browser?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I fixed using:

```
    String url = null;
    try {
        url = URLEncoder.encode("YOUR_URL", "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    web_view.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url);
```